# How to update item status and progress bar in listview ?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with a lots of items, you can selected multiple items and download.I have a download manager class which is using download file, and update status and progress by callback method(interface).

When callback is invoked, it will get viewholder via current item position.

All things are fine for currently.

The question is when I scroll listview, it may crashed. The reason is when I get viewholder, getview is invoked, and scroll listview also trigger getview method.

How to process this situation ?

Comment: can u post a code snippet of your BaseAdapter getView method?

Comment: I found a simple solution:

Using OnScrollListener() of listview, set a flag to save scrolling state. checking scrolling state while updating viewholder.

It works for me.

Comment: OK good for you. But it would be better to look at it.. :)